# unable to set cookies in selenium webdriver because Date is depriciated

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here ,while setting Date it is not working because Date is depriciated in eclipse.

```
       Date expiry = null;  


          String val = token.nextToken();
       if(!val.equals("null"))
        {   

            expiry = new Date(val);;                    
       }        
        Boolean isSecure = new Boolean(token.nextToken()).booleanValue();
```

Comment: Which library you are using Java Util or Java SQL ?

Comment: Yes in this code i am using java Util

Answer (score 0):

use like this...

```
expiry = java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance().parse(val);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.